# Single regexp to get page URL but exclude port number from a full URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm trying to come up with a regexp to get the page URL from the full URL but exclude a possible port number from it. So far I came up with the following JS:

```
var res = url.match(/^.*\:\/\/(?:www2?.)?([^?#]+)/i);
if(res)
{
    var pageURL = res[1];
    console.log(pageURL);
}
```

If I call it for this:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/php/page.php?what=sw#print";
```

I get the correct answer: `example.com/php/page.php`

But if I do:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com:80/php/page.php?what=sw#print";
```

I need it to return `example.com/php/page.php` instead of `example.com:80/php/page.php`.

I can remove it with the second regexp, but I was curious if I could do it with just one (for speed)?

Comment: Use urijs, don't use regexes for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your regex to this:

```
/^.*\:\/\/(?:www2?.)?([^/:]+)(?:[^:]*:\d+)?([^?#]+)/i
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/4)

It will return 2 matches:

```
1: example.com
2: /php/page.php
```

as `match[1]` and `match[2]` respectively for both inputs that you can **concatenate**.

```
http://www.example.com/php/page.php?what=sw#print
```

OR

```
http://www.example.com:80/php/page.php?what=sw#print
```

**Update:** Here are **[performance results on jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/hostname-from-url/19)** that shows regex method is **fastest** is of all.

Comment: Thanks. You got it. I didn't think about concatenating two results. And performance difference of the regexp is amazing, isn't it.

Comment: Yes no doubt I was also amazed to look at the performance results of regex method.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a regex at all?

---

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @c00000fd: Because `document` might not be available and `document.createElement` is very slow compared to RegExp - see:

http://jsperf.com/url-parsing/5

http://jsperf.com/hostname-from-url

Nevertheless I will leave my original answer for reference.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Instead you could just use the `Anchor` element:

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/12qjqx7n/

**JS:**

```
var url = 'http://foo:bar@www.example.com:8080/php/page.php?what=sw#print'
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;

console.log(a.hash);
console.log(a.host);
console.log(a.hostname);
console.log(a.origin);
console.log(a.password);
console.log(a.pathname);
console.log(a.port);
console.log(a.protocol);
console.log(a.search);
console.log(a.username);
```

**Additional information:**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_anchor.asp

Comment: Because it is **very** slow. Plus I might not have access to the `document` object.

Comment: Ok - without document this might not be so easy ;) ... but regarding the performance of RegExp vs createElement - do you have numbers on that? That would be interesting :)

Comment: I should say that this is my preferred method of "chopping up" URLs into pieces... as long as performance is not an issue, and, well, you can access `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
~ node 
> "http://www.example.com:3000/php/page.php?what=sw#print".replace(/:\d+/, '');
'http://www.example.com/php/page.php?what=sw#print'
> "http://www.example.com/php/page.php?what=sw#print".replace(/:\d+/, '');
'http://www.example.com/php/page.php?what=sw#print'
```

Comment: A second regexp call for what?

Answer (score 0):

How about a group for matching the port, if present?

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com:80/php/page.php?what=sw#print";
var res = url.match(/^.*\:\/\/(?:www2?.)?([^?#\/:]+)(\:\d+)?(\/[^?#]+)/i);
if(res)
{
    var pageURL = res[1]+res[3];
    console.log(res, pageURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var url = "http://www.example.com:80/php/page.php?what=sw#print";
var res = url.split(/\w+:\/\/+\w+\.|:+\d+|\?.*/).join("");
```

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com:80/php/page.php?what=sw#print";
var res = url.split(/\w+:\/\/+\w+\.|:+\d+|\?.*/).join("");
document.body.innerText = res;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use replace method to modify your original string or Url,

```
> var url = "http://www.example.com/php/page.php?what=sw#print";
undefined
> var url1 = "http://www.example.com:80/php/page.php?what=sw#print";
undefined
> url.replace(/^.*?:\/\/(?:www2?.)?([^/:]+)(?::\d+)?([^?#]+).*$/g, "$1$2")
'example.com/php/page.php'
> url1.replace(/^.*?:\/\/(?:www2?.)?([^/:]+)(?::\d+)?([^?#]+).*$/g, "$1$2")
'example.com/php/page.php'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/5)